# WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: uniform1i: location not for current program

Tags: google-chrome, webgl

I'm trying to setup two textures in my fragment shader but am getting this error if I try setup the corresponding uniform variables with:

`gl.uniform1i(getUniformLocation(program, "uTextureOne"), 0);` and `gl.uniform1i(getUniformLocation(program, "uTextureTwo"), 1);`.

What does it mean? (I'm using Chrome)

My shader looks like this:

```
        "#ifdef GL_ES                       \r\n" +
        "precision mediump float;           \r\n" + 
        "#endif                             \r\n" +
        "uniform sampler2D uTextureOne;     \r\n" +
        "uniform sampler2D uTextureTwo;     \r\n" +
        "varying vec3 vOrgNormal;           \r\n" +
        "void main(void) {                  \r\n" +
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

“Location not for current program” means that the active shader program (`gl.useProgram`) is not the program which you obtained the uniform locations from.

If you are using only one shader program, then simply make sure that in your initialization you do `gl.useProgram` before you do any `gl.uniform…`.

If you are using multiple shader programs, make sure that the correct one is selected before you attempt to set uniform values. Note that uniforms are specific to programs and they are remembered by the programs, so you don't have to re-set them every time you switch programs!

Comment: and what about three.js? I have the same warnings in my three.js scene

Comment: @QuentinD I am not familiar with three.js and cannot help you. Please [post a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) — you can include a link to this one if you think it'd be useful context.